# Dual suspension to monoshock

Tags: motorcycle, suspension, bajaj, custom

I have a Bajaj Discover 135 with dual suspension.  I have seen some photos on Google of some people who have successfully done this conversion.

***Now my question is, what would be the steps to do this?***

What i found is that it could be adapted to the fork it currently has but I wanted to find out how the process would be.  I have done some research into the matter and not many mechanics around here seem to have the knowledge to do such a thing. I have tried looking into a more recent model that has the mono-shock but to buy the mono-shock and fork goes over budget.  I opted into looking for other options.

***Can someone give a summary of what I would need to do to accomplish my goal of putting a mono-shock rear end on my motorcycle?***

Comment: welcome to the site and thanks for the question.  I've edited it a bit for you.  Please validate I haven't changed the meaning.  Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

**You will need to make several changes to the frame**

Currently your rear subframe is bossed and strengthened considerably as all of the absorbed energy from road undulations is transferred from your swingarm to the rear subframe, underneath your seat and tail section.

With a cantilever swingarm you will need a rear single shock mount point.  You would need to build this and weld up your frame.  If you are not well versed in frame technology and physics I would suggest you have this component created and installed by a professional frame craftsman.  It would more than likely need to go where your current battery and air box are located.

**Migration**

You would need to migrate the location of your battery and perhaps even remove your airbox.  If you remove your airbox you will need individual air cleaners for your carburetors.  A re-jetting of your carburetors will also be in order if you do this.

You can get a small racing battery and put it in your tail section.  You will be very unhappy with this small battery the first time you try and start your motorcycle more than a few times and it doesn't work.  Get used to push starting your bike from time to time.

**Swingarm**

You will need a cantilever swingarm.  If you do this, you may as well get a Honda SuperHawk single sided swingarm because, why not?  Your biggest issue is going to be the mount point on the frame though, followed by aligning your chain properly and shimming your front sprocket appropriately and possibly cutting the downtube on the left side of the bike so the chain has clearance.

**Big Project**

Here is a summary

- Remove the airbox
- Get individual filters for carbs
- Re-jet carbs
- Migrate battery to tail section in order to have an open frame triangle without obstructions below the rider (it's cafe style)
- Procure battery that fits into the tail section behind the brake/tail light
- Rewire for new battery location
- Modify frame for single shock
- Procure new swing arm
- Procure new shock to match
- Re-valve shock for weight of rider and bike
- Procure appropriate spring for shock
- Modify sprocket alignment
- Possibly cut downtube of left side of frame for chain clearance
- Procure new rim to match swingarm
- Procure new rear brake that will mount to swing arm
- Procure new axle for new rim
- Procure new rim
- Make alignment spacers for proper rim fitment on axle
- Procure new tire for new rim size
- Procure new chain alignment adjusters to match swingarm
- Procure or make new swingarm shaft to go through frame
- Put appropriate bearings in swingarm to match new swingarm shaft

There you have it.  That's a short list off the top of my head.

If there is a monoshock solution for your bike where you can take all the pieces off a different model and modify the frame it will make it much easier.  You will still need to go through everything I've listed but if someone has done it before it certainly makes it quite a bit easier.

Comment: Business as usual.. :-)